# Join tables with some same values

Tags: join, group-by

I'm trying to get lines that have same ADAPTERID and Attribute_Name, but Attribute_Value can be active or designed automatically. 
I used:

```
SELECT * FROM database1 
where Attribute_Value IN ('ACTIVE','DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY')
and Attribute_Name = 'State'
and ADAPTERID = '1277667'
```

and I get:

```
ADAPTERID   CFS_Name        Attribute_Name  Attribute_Value
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           ACTIVE
```

How can I get these  that are actually only different ones:

```
ADAPTERID   CFS_Name        Attribute_Name  Attribute_Value
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY
1277667     1277667-Željka  State           ACTIVE
```

thanks

Comment: Where's the join? Are you looking for the `DISTINCT` clause?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the records that have more than one value in `Attribute_Value` then you can't simply use filters on a `WHERE` because you want to validate rows in a group (a `WHERE` will filter by row, not by set).

Try using a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to check existance of multiple values for a particular set, then use this result to display the proper records.

```
SELECT
    D.Attribute_Name,
    D.ADAPTERID,
    D.Attribute_Value
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Attribute_Name,
            ADAPTERID 
        FROM 
            database1 
        WHERE
            Attribute_Value IN ('ACTIVE','DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY')
        GROUP BY
            Attribute_Name,
            ADAPTERID
        HAVING
            COUNT(DISTINCT(Attribute_Value)) > 1
    ) Mult
    INNER JOIN database1 D ON
        Mult.Attribute_Name = D.Attribute_Name AND
        Mult.ADAPTERID = D.ADAPTERID
```

This will still display multiple records with the same `Attribute_Value` if repeated (by `Attribute_Name` and `ADAPTERID`), then you can just add `DISTINCT` right after `SELECT` to see uniques. You might also want to filter by `Attribute_Value` on the outmost `SELECT` in case you are just interested in this values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    D.Attribute_Name,
    D.ADAPTERID,
    D.Attribute_Value
-- ...
```

Also the `INNER JOIN` will filter rows that have `NULL` value on either `Attribute_Name` or `ADAPTERID` (on most databases). If you still want to display them you will have to add `NULL` check functions (the syntax depends on the DBMS, like `ISNULL()` for SQL Server or `NVL()` for Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Try using DISTINCT..

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM database1 
where Attribute_Value IN ('ACTIVE','DESIGNED AUTOMATICALLY')
and Attribute_Name = 'State'
and ADAPTERID = '1277667'
```

Comment: Given your sample data set this shouldn't return the same results.

Comment: One possibility I can think of is the values in CFS_Name columns are not identical. try exclusing that column from SELECT clause or trim the column may be